# How can I iterate over items in onBindViewHolder without using a RecyclerView instance in the adapter method?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have implemented a rewarded ad feature in my app, where clicking on a lock icon shows an ad and on successful completion of the ad, I want to replace all the lock icons with copy icons in the entire list. However, the current code I have for replacing the icons requires the use of a RecyclerView variable, and it needs to be instantiated in the adapter method, causing issues in the MainActivity since I'm only using the list and context there. I apologize for any grammar errors, I've done my best to explain the situation.

Here is the code

```
private final RecyclerView recyclerView;


    public MemeAdapter(List<String> memeList, Context mContext, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        this.memeList = memeList;
        this.context = mContext;
        this.rewardGranted = recyclerView;

        mSharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        rewardGranted = mSharedPrefs.getBoolean(REWARD_GRANTED_KEY, false);
    }
```

inside the bindviewholder

```
 @Override
                                public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                    // Called when ad is dismissed.
                                    // Set the ad reference to null so you don't show the ad a second time.
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Ad dismissed fullscreen content.");
                                    mRewardedVideoAd = null;
                                    for (int i = 0; i < memeList.size(); i++) {
                                        // Get the corresponding view holder for this item
                                        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);

                                        // Update the icons for this item
                                        if (holder instanceof MemeAdapter.MemeViewHolder) {
                                            MemeAdapter.MemeViewHolder itemHolder = (MemeAdapter.MemeViewHolder) holder;
                                            itemHolder.copyImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            itemHolder.lockImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                    }

//                                    holder.copyImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                                    holder.lockImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    mSharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean(REWARD_GRANTED_KEY, rewardGranted).apply();
                                }
```

Her is the error im getting

```
error: constructor MemeAdapter in class MemeAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
        MemeAdapter adapter = new MemeAdapter(asciiArts, this);
                              ^
  required: List<String>,Context,RecyclerView
  found: List<String>,MainActivity
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Answer (score 1):

All the updates of recyclerview should be caused by the adapter - that's the "single source of truth" for the recycler. The basic idea is that when you call `notifyXxxChanged` you tell the adapter that some data changed and you want to update the display. It will call `onBindViewHolder` for all the changed data allowing you to choose a new way to display it.

As a starting point you can do this:

Store data as `List<Pair<String, Boolean>> memeList`. The first element of the pair is the string you previously stored. The second one is a boolean flag indicating which image to show.

Update stored data inside `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent`:

```
@Override
public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
    // Called when ad is dismissed.
    // Set the ad reference to null so you don't show the ad a second time.
    Log.d(TAG, "Ad dismissed fullscreen content.");
    mRewardedVideoAd = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < memeList.size(); i++) {
        memeList[i].second = true;
    }
    notifyDataRangeChanged(0, memeList.size()); // tell adapter to update all data. More efficient than notifyDatasetChanged
    mSharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean(REWARD_GRANTED_KEY, rewardGranted).apply();
}
```

Inside `onBindViewHolder` display correct image:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(...) {
    ...
    if (memeList[position].second) {
        itemHolder.copyImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                              
        itemHolder.lockImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        itemHolder.copyImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);                              
        itemHolder.lockImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```